# How to get a computer's internet (IP address) location using command line?

Tags: internet, ip, geolocation

How to get a computer's internet (IP address) location using command line?

For example, using curl or wget?

Comment: Could you specify what an "internet location" is?

Comment: The IP's address location. Adding to the questions...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a service providing this: [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io).

You can invoke it using `curl`. Example:

```
curl ipinfo.io
```

Result:

```
{
  "ip": "...",
  "hostname": "...",
  "city": "...",
  "region": "...",
  "country": "...",
  "loc": "...,...",
  "org": "..."
}
```

A specific IP's info can also be requested: `curl ipinfo.io/216.58.194.46`:

```
{
  "ip": "216.58.194.46",
  "hostname": "dfw25s12-in-f14.1e100.net",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.4192,-122.0574",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "postal": "94043"
}
```

https is also available: `curl https://ipinfo.io/216.58.194.46`

Source: http://xmodulo.com/geographic-location-ip-address-command-line.html

Comment: Please note this service does not provide an accurate location. 50km wrong for me.

Comment: Perhaps it provides the ISP's location?

Comment: I've no idea how it works. I'm currently on mobile internet. Google maps manages to locate me perfectly well.

Comment: The curl command above just goes to a service without providing anything private. ipinfo.io has almost only the source IP to use to pin point the location and get data.

Comment: I know. That's fine as long as you are happy with inaccurate data.

Comment: geoip is notoriously inaccurate... I can be either in Idaho, Minnesota or Oregon depending on the DHCP netblock of the day.

Comment: @DavidPostill Google Maps uses GPS to position you on the map, it's pretty accurate. Geolocation by IP address usually gets region right.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I am aware of that. Google maps is accurate. For me Geolocation by IP address returns a complete different city (I call that inaccurate). I am using mobile tethering ;)

Comment: _Google maps is accurate_ unless a demolition company uses it for directions after a tornado passes through, as happened recently. With Google Maps, trust, but verify very heavily before doing anything that has financial consequences.

Comment: IP based geolocation provides what the company that is providing the IP chooses to display with its records. There is no real standard that seems to be followed. I have seen the address of my ISP show up instead of my own location for example when checking my personal IP over the years.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question doesn't specify an OS, this is how to get that same information with PowerShell's `curl` (actually an alias of `Invoke-WebRequest`):

```
(curl ipinfo.io).Content
```

That produces a JSON string. To get the object that JSON represents, use `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
curl ipinfo.io | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Since that's a PowerShell object, you can easily get specific fields from it. For example, this command gets just the external IP as a string:

```
(curl ipinfo.io | ConvertFrom-Json).ip
```

Note that the geographical information from this service isn't super accurate, but it did locate me within 20 miles or so. The ISP information seems to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use from PowerShell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json
```

The command output will already give us the location in JSON

Extracted from: https://www.sysadmit.com/2019/01/windows-saber-ip-publica-PowerShell.html