# How can I obtain IP information without third party tools in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

There are some websites like [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/) that give clients some information for an IP address like location, ASN and etc. How can I obtain mentioned information without third party tools in Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a computer's internet (IP address) location using command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1065263/how-to-get-a-computers-internet-ip-address-location-using-command-line)

Comment: The answers for [that question](https://superuser.com/questions/1065263/how-to-get-a-computers-internet-ip-address-location-using-command-line) are using third party tools

Comment: Curl is a third party tool?

Comment: `curl` is not a third party tool, but [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io) is a third party tool.

Comment: There is no way that you can download locally the entire database used by `ipinfo.io`, or if you do then to use it. You need an external repository.

Comment: Unless you construct a local DB of all locations of all IP addresses (and maintain it...) you'll have to use 3rd party servers for this. For the purely network information, `whois` and `dig` will help.

Comment: Thank @xenoid very much, using `whois` is the answer that I was looking for it, if you can answer this question by yourself to make this question an answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you construct a local DB of all locations of all IP addresses (and maintain it...) you'll have to use 3rd party servers for this.

For the purely network information, whois and dig will help.